# Service available in Visual Studio but not via IIS

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2012, iis-7

I seem to occasionally see issues in my development environment where a SOAP service is available and working fine when started via Visual Studio (2012).  But in IIS 7 it is not accessible at all. It returns a 503 error which seems useless.  i cant really even debug in this state. i cant even do a directory browse from IIS when browsing is enable.

I'm looking to understand what could cause this inconsistent behavior.  What might i try to further analyze the problem?

Comment: Have you looked at this link http://www.brainbrushups.com/2013/07/solve-http-error-503-service-is.html

Comment: Is it a WCF service? If so, how are you hosting it?

Comment: it is WCF.  what do you mean by how am i hosting it?

Comment: @Namphibian. yes, that was the problem. the app pool was stopped. and it keeps getting stopped again and again after i restart it.  i suppose this means some sort of crash is occurring in the service?

Comment: @glutz Consult the Windows Application Event Log and look for events logged by IIS that will explain why the process crashes.

Answer (score 1):

IIS Error 503 is often caused by an Application Pool misconfiguration, such as an incorrect User Identity. When you run your service from VS it will run in VS's own hosting process or maybe IIS Express, but when you use the full IIS server it will run in a different Application Pool process, so this is where the problem lies - it also explains why nothing else seems to be working in that website for you.